# Print PHP running call stack from outside the PHP

Tags: php, debugging, stack-trace

Is there any runtime stack trace feature in PHP, by a given PID of it?
(For whom also write Java, I mean jstack.)

I got few PHP background process that they are freeze once a while on some unknown lines. I can simply kill them all and restart but that don't prevent it happen again.

Is there a API able to spy the stack and tell? like the jstack utility provided from JDK?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options in terms of debugging unknown errors.

- The first method is easy, but requires a PHP extension to be installed.
- The second method offers a more difficult hands-on approach, but is definitely worth it if you're into the low-level inner-workings of the PHP interpreter. Also, this will require linux and PHP to be configured with `--enable-debug`.
- The third and, in my personal opinion the easiest, method doesn't require the use of any external programs or added PHP extensions.

---

1. [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org)

   - This is a PHP extension you can [install](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/install) and have available for any site/page.
   - A quick-list of features from the website:

     - Automatic stack trace upon error
     - Function call logging
     - Display features such as enhanced var_dump() output and code coverage information.
   - If you see yourself needing to debug your scripts a lot, this one might be the best option. The prettier-display of errors is also a good thumbs-up in my book.
2. Use [`gdb`](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php) to run the file that crashes and analyze the backtrace.

   - This is an intermediate-to-advanced approach that requires PHP to be configured with `--enable-debug`, a linux machine running `Apache`, and a strong desire/ability to understand the way software works on a lower-level.
   - Run `gdb` with `Apache`:
     `gdb /usr/lib/httpd`
   - Then, you have two options.:

     - Run apache as a server and load the file through a browser, as normal:
       `(gdb) run -X`
       ... now, in your browser - access the page that crashes as normal and switch back to `gdb`:
       `(gdb) backtrace`
       ... the full backtrace will be printed
     - Or, use `gdb` to run the script itself:
       `(gdb) run /path/to/the/script.php`
       `(gdb) backtrace`
       ... the full backtrace will be printed
   - For more `gdb` info, check out the [quick-reference guide](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/gdb5-refcard.pdf).
3. Create a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) that prints the stack trace when an error is thrown.

   - To be sure to catch *all* errors, you can catch Errors, Exceptions, and PHP's Shutdown events.
   - To debug a single page, it's as simple as creating a function to handle the error and then pasting that function into the top of the page you're having issues on. One step further, I have an "error handling" class that's in a separate file and just include it whenever needed (simplified-version below). You can tweak each method to suit your display needs, or even handle errors on a per-error-number basis!
   - Then, to use this, just add `require('ErrorHandler.php');` to the top of your page and it should auto-register itself to handle any errors. Be sure to update the include-path to point to the actual file, of course.

ErrorHandler.php:

```
<?php
class ErrorHandler {
    public static function captureError($err_no, $message, $file, $line) {
        echo '<strong>Error (#' . $err_no . '):</strong> ' . $message . ' in ' . $file . ' on line #' . $line . '<br />';
        debug_print_backtrace();
    }

    public static function captureException($exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
    }

    public static function captureShutdown() {
        if (($error = error_get_last()) !== null) {
            debug_print_backtrace();
        }
    }
}
set_error_handler(array('ErrorHandler', 'captureError'));
set_exception_handler(array('ErrorHandler', 'captureException'));
register_shutdown_function(array('ErrorHandler', 'captureShutdown'));
?>
```